# Azure DevOps Pipeline variables define automatically change before build

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps build pipeline with some pipeline variables.

I would like to change it, one of the variables automatically with powershell script, right before queueing.
Is it possible?

Or is there any other way to work with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "20.2.35". 20.2 part should be updated manually once year, but .35 should be updated every week, this is week number

I am afraid that there is no variable that can achieve weekly increments. But you can use [scheduled triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [counter variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter) to achieve similar functions.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a Variable Group in `Pipeline -> Library`.

[image]

2. Create two Pipelines. Pipeline 1 use the Counter to update the variable in variable group(every week). Pipeline 2 set the variable as the Buildnumber.

Example:

Pipeline 1 Use powershell task to run the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to update the variable.

```
trigger:
- none

schedules:
  - cron: "0 12 * * 0"
    displayName: Weekly Sunday build
    branches:
       include:
         - master

variables:
  - name: version
    value: $[counter('',36)]

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $token = "PAT"
      
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{Group ID}?api-version=6.1-preview.2"
      
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      
      $JSON = @'
      {
         "variables":{"{variable name}":{"value":"$(version)"}},"id":{Group ID},"type":"Vsts","name":"{Variable Group name}","variableGroupProjectReferences":[{"projectReference":{"id":"{Project ID}","name":"{Project Name}"},"name":"{Variable Group Name}"}]
      }
      '@
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PUT -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

Pipeline 2. Use the Variable to set the Buildnumber.

```
name: 20.2 $(123)

trigger:
- none

variables:
  - group: test

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

**Explaination:**

Pipeline1 will run once a week to update the variable value. And the value will be incremented by 1. Pipeline2 uses this variable to set the build number. This value has been set before the pipeline runs, you can use `$(build.buildnumber)` to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell

The variable have to be declared in the pipeline and you can set a value with output (from cmd, powerhsell, python, exe, ...) :

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVariable;]NewValue
```

In PowerShell, you can use `Write-Host` :

```bsh
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVariable;]NewValue"
```

Comment: But can it be executed right before build? Cos I'm using this variable in the build name.

Comment: I miss your question, sorry. I don't think you can execute script before build. Can you specify your need?

Comment: I use this variable to create name of build, so in case of automatically builds, I would like to update this variable before building.

Comment: It should contain such text: "20.2.35". 20.2 part should be updated manually once year, but .35 should be updated every week, this is week number

Comment: In your build definition, in Options you can parameterized the build number : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Comment: Sure, I use this variable in Options, but also I need to put this variable to product version, so I'm trying to use the same variable for two purpose, and trying to do maximum automatically.

Comment: How do you set product version? Maybe you can use the variable `$(Build.BuildNumber)`?